# Return certain parts of a page with php

Tags: php, html

How can I return only the body of a PHP file?
An example of how the file would look like:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content"><p>Hello World</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I only return the body of the page with PHP?

```
<div class="content"><p>Hello World</p></div>
```

I would use a GET variable to indicate I only require the body, else the entire page is needed.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? so if a user clicks on one of your links, it just removes the body, and adds the new page body?  Have you thought about using jquery for this instead? I don't think it's possible with php. How many pages are we talking here?

Comment: @lawnlanders The idea is that when a user clicks on a link on a page, instead of using jquery to get the entire page, headers and all, it just gets the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
  // read and interpret your GET-input variable: 
  $body_only = isset($_GET['body_only']); // you can enhance/change this condition to match your needs

  if(!$body_only)
  {
    // if NOT only body was requested, output intro (head, etc.): 
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
  }

  // always output body content: 
?>
<div class="content"><p>Hello World</p></div>
<?php 
  if(!$body_only)
  {
    // if NOT only body was requested, output outro: 
?>
</body>
</html>
<?php 
  }
?>
```

Personally, I prefer usual C-style syntax in such cases (i.e. `<?php if(...) { ?> ... <?php } ?>`), so I've used it in the code above. 
PHP also offers alternative syntax, which you may find more readable:

```
<?php if (...): ?>
  This will show if the expression is true.
<?php else: ?>
  Otherwise this will show.
<?php endif; ?>
```

[Read this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php) for more info on escaping PHP code from HTML.

Also, consider using a template engine.

Answer (score 0):

There's the [PHP DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) you can use, it is quite simple and doesn't really need any explanation however if you find yourself having trouble don't worry to write a comment!